# UWP Binding: Changing backgrounds in XAML using C#

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

Suppose I am making a simple UWP application which navigates through several pages. I would like to have a common background for all pages, depending on which background a user has selected from the Settings page.

I have a `SettingsPage.xaml` with a comboBox (and Grid Background that needs to change):

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox Name="ColourSelect" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Red">Red</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Green">Green</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Blue">Blue</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Which interfaces with my `SettingsPage.xaml.cs` file:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change background
        if (Red.IsSelected) { } // Change to Red.png
        else if (Green.IsSelected) { } // Change to Green.png
        else if (Blue.IsSelected) { } // Change to Blue.png
    }
```

I have set up my `App.xaml` to contain a background resource, but I'm not sure how to bind it to the C# in `Settings.xaml.cs`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="CommonBackground">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ <!-- Some image. How to bind? --> }"
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

What should I return to bind the user decision to the Application resources?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why give an own color template - when you can support whole themes of windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires few changes in different pieces of application. Follow my steps.

In this case I a am creating two Resources. One that will maintain the Settings `Combobox` Colour Scheme. Second one is `BitMapImage` in Resource.

So my Application.Resource will look something like below.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <image:BitmapImage x:Key="BackgroundSource" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Red.png" />
    <x:String x:Key="BackgroundBrush">Red</x:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

Make sure you are adding `xmlns:image="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging"` in your App.xaml.

Now Create a Static Method inside App.xaml.cs that will be used to update `Background` to the Page during Run time. It should be something like below.

```
public static void UpdateBGColors(string Color)
{
    switch (Color)
    {
        case "Red":
            Current.Resources["BackgroundSource"] = "ms-appx:///Assets/Red.png";
            break;
        case "Green":
            Current.Resources["BackgroundSource"] = "ms-appx:///Assets/Green.png";
            break;
        case "Blue":
            Current.Resources["BackgroundSource"] = "ms-appx:///Assets/Blue.png";
            break;
        default:
            Current.Resources["BackgroundSource"] = "ms-appx:///Assets/Red.png";
            break;
    }
}
```

Now Your `combobox_SelectionChanged` should look like below.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;

    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    localSettings.Values["BackgroundBrush"] = (cb.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content;
    App.UpdateBGColors((cb.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString());
}
```

Now you need to wire up the Background of each page to the Resource `BackgroundSource`. So anywhere you want the background to be set based on settings add below lines of code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource BackgroundSource}" />
    </Grid.Background>
    ......
</Grid>
```

At this point, if you change the setting in setting page and if you navigate back to original page that you came into setting page, The background should be set automatically to whatever you selected in Settings.

But you also want to make sure the same background is loaded when the app is opened next time. To do that in `App.xaml.cs`, Add below lines in the beginning of `OnLaunched` Event.

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (localSettings.Values["BackgroundBrush"] != null)
{
    UpdateBGColors(localSettings.Values["BackgroundBrush"].ToString());
}
```

Since in settings page, you are saving `BackgroundBrush` Everytime you change the Combobox Item, Whenever your app is loading, Based on the `BackgroundBrush` `BackgroundSource` will be assigned to correct Uri and will be used as Page Backhground.

Full Repo is available [Here](https://github.com/avknaidu/SO44830556)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Update] You can use this, and after save your settings.

SettingsPage.xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="colorImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <ComboBox Name="ColourSelect" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Red">Red</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Green">Green</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Blue">Blue</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Red.IsSelected)
        {
            ChangeColorImage("ms-appx:///Assets/Red.png");
        } 
        else if (Green.IsSelected)
        {
            ChangeColorImage("ms-appx:///Assets/Green.png");
        }
        else if (Blue.IsSelected)
        {
            ChangeColorImage("ms-appx:///Assets/Blue.png");
        }
    }

    private void ChangeColorImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        // using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
        BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));
        colorImage.ImageSource = imageSource;
    }
```